# Submit button not working inside @section mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, razor, submit, html.beginform

I got this problem and i can't find a solution.
I put a submit button inside a @section so I can put it inside a div in the layout page. But the problem is that the submit button doesn't work when inside the section.

Here is the view, the section en the submit button are almost at the bottom of the page

```
@{
var vd = new MvcVerkoop.Models.VerkoopsData();
var data = vd.KoperData; }

@using (Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Kies de nodige velden</legend>


    <table class="velden">

        @foreach (string var in data)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBox(var)
                    <label for="Naam">@var</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBox("Verplicht" + @var)
                    <label for="Verlpicht">Verplicht veld</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }


        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="input1" class="clonedInput">

                    @Html.TextBox("extra1")
                </div>

            </td>

            <td>
                <div id="inputCheck1" class="clonedInputCheck">
                    @Html.CheckBox("checkVerplicht1")

                    <label for="checkVerplicht1" id="labelVerplicht1">Verplicht veld</label>
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="-" />
    </div>

    @section Bottom{

        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Doorgaan" />
    }

</fieldset>}
```

When the submit button is outside the section is works fine.

EDIT: layout code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <div class="top-menu">

        </div>
</header>
<div id="body">
    <div class="centre-box">
        <div class="centre-banner">
        </div>

        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <div class="centre-footer">
            @RenderSection("Bottom", false)
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>© @DateTime.Now.Year Code Express</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling RenderSection("Bottom") in your layout file?

Comment: Yes, I'll put the layout code in the post

Comment: Is this a partial view?

Comment: No just a regular view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can only assume that when the button is inside the section that it is being rendered outside of the form.

I assume you want to put the button inside the section so you can share that button across many forms? If so you'll have to use JavaScript to hook a submit on the click event of the button, because the button is no longer part of a form.

You'll also then have to hook up an event for when someone hits enter too to submit the form.

I would just create a distinct button for each form you want to submit. A lot less hassle.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: I'm using a section so I can put the button (different button in each view) inside a div. Maybe there is an other way to do this.

Comment: I found a solution using your advice, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had the same problem and I thought i'd post the solution so people don't have to trawl through other posts to get the issue resolved.

In the begin form, set the id

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes:new { id = "mainForm" }))
```

Then on the submit button set the form property to the value of the id

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Doorgaan" form="mainForm" />
```

That fixed it for me.